# trivial rules in association rules algorithm

Tags: data-mining, apriori

I analysis database of supermarket by association rules algorithm although, min confidence(0.04)  and min support(0.002) is  low but result that got them is trivial rule ( fresh items that bought daily)  for example:

Tomato -->  Cucumber

Milk --> eggs

I don’t thing this rules may be benefit for any thing.

I use sql server business intelligence for analysis.

Is it possible that my database  can not help me in the forecasting or other problem

Comment: Why are these not good rules? Sounds pretty much like the definition of a good association rule to me. It tells you what items are strongly correlated. (Of course rules with more than 2 items get more interesting.)

Comment: Not good rule because it is fresh items that bought daily continuous for example vegetables already bought with each other not rules I think good rule for example 

oil – rice

or 

oil -- Soup powder

Comment: Well, try to make that a *mathematical* property. In my opinion, tomato & cucumber *is* a good rule, based on confidence and support as definitions for "good".

Answer (score 0):

Confidence, by itself, does not tell you much.  You also need to consider lift (how much more likely are cucumbers when tomato is present than when tomato is not present). You can also use the chi-square value calculated from a contingency table with counts of cucumbers when tomatoes are present and not present. A higher chi-square value generally indicates a more interesting rule.